# React optimize functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two React functional components `Parent` and `Node`. `Parent` renders list of `Node` components and passes click handler to each `Node`. When I click on the `Node`, in the `Parent` the new state is set and all components rerenders.

```js
const Parent = (props) => {

  const [clickedList, setClickedList] = useState([]);

  const onNodeClick = (node) => {
    let newList = [...clickedList, node];
    setClickedList(newList);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {someNodes.map(node => <Node key={node.id} node={node} onNodeClick={props.onNodeClick}/>)}
    </div>
  )
}


const Node = (props) => {

  const handleClick = (node) => {
    props.onNodeClick(node);
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={() => handleClick(node)}>
      {props.node.name}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The list of nodes contains more than 400 items. Rerendering of each component takes time. I tried to use `React.memo` for `Node` component, but the feature is that I pass the function to `Node`, which has different references after each rerendering of the `Parent` and `React.memo` component rerenders too. Also I tried to provide a custom comparison function for `React.memo` where I skip comparsion of passed function. The result is components do not rerender, but component state `clickedList` does not change in the click handler in the `Parent`.

I also tried to use `useCallback` hook on the click handler in the `Parent`, the result is similar. If I give no dependencies `[]` then component state `clickedList` does not change.

```js
const memorizedNodeClick = useCallback(
  (node) => {
    onNodeClick(node);
  }, [],
);
```

If I give state in dependencies `[clickedList]` then all more than 400 components rerenders

```js
const memorizedNodeClick = useCallback(
  (node) => {
    onNodeClick(node);
  }, [clickedList],
);
```

How can I prevent unnecessary component rendering and keep all clicked items in the `clickedList` state?

Comment: sorry, from the provided code example it's not evident why do you need to rerender Node component, which data changes, right now it looks like nothing changes, so no need to rerender them, could you pls provide this info

Comment: @ИльяСавич thanks for the response. I do not need to rerender Node component, I want to prevent its rerenders, because the result of rerendering is the same. Now Node component rerenders, I think it is so because I pass function as prop